# Implement python ttk.notebook with graph

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a tkinter GUI python ver 2.7. The code is:

```
Main = Tk()
Main.tk_setPalette(background='white')
Time(Main)
init()
GenerateMenus(Main)
w = GenerateDisplay(Main)
n = ttk.Notebook(Main, width= 800, height =400)
n.grid(row=6,column=0, columnspan=9)
f1 = ttk.Frame(n);
f2 = ttk.Frame(n);
n.add(f2, text='Two')
n.add(f1, text='One')
GenerateGraph(f1)
```

Code for Generating Graph

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import *
from random import *
import Tkinter as tk

f = Figure(figsize=(5.5,3.5), dpi=120)
rc("font", size = 7)
Figure
a = f.add_subplot(111)
xList = []
yList = []
x= 0
y = 0

def animate(i):
    global x
    global y
    xList.append(int(x))
    yList.append(int(y))

    y = randint(0,100)
    x += 5

    a.clear()
    a.plot(xList, yList)
    a.set_ylim(0,100)
    a.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
    a.set_ylabel("Acceleration (m/s2)")


def GenerateGraph(Master):
    dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=Master)
    dataPlot.show()
    dataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(dataPlot, Master)
    toolbar.update()
    dataPlot._tkcanvas.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

The rest of the GUI is displayed but the graph is not. I am new to tkinter and would like to know how to edit this code so that the graph shows inside a notebook tab.

Comment: this code does not show how the graph itself is generated, to help you we would need to know the code behind `GenerateGraph`

Comment: I have edited so that it shows the code for generating graph.

Comment: what are the necessary import statements? what is the GenerateDisplay function? Have you been able to resolve the issue?

Comment: The issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is pass the notebook variable i.e. `n` as the `Master` in the line

```
dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=Master)
```

and hence you would not need the lines

```
dataPlot.show()
dataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr Parate,

I couldn't find this information in any place but here and it worked to me in python 3.8. It opened the plot in n  not in one of the tabs though. I had to do (in my OOP version):

self.f1 = ttk.Frame(n);
self.f2 = ttk.Frame(n);

#and then

```
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.ica_Tab_01) 
    self.canvas.draw()

    # position of canvas:
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, rowspan=2, column=0, columnspan=20, sticky='NEWS')
```

and it worked fine. Thank you very much!